# Access /var/www/html/website symbolic link from home user folder

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, permissions, sftp

I have a VPS OS: ubuntu 15.04, in which i have one website in /var/www/html/WEBSITE
/var/www/html/WEBSITE have www-data:www-data as user:group

I created a symbolic link with

```
ls -s /var/www/html/WEBSITE /home/USER1/WEBSITE
```

To allow access USER1 to  /var/www/html/WEBSITE with sftp
I have created a user USER1 with this command

```
sudo useradd -d /home/user1 -m User1 -g sftp -s /bin/false
```

/home/USER1/WEBSITE root:root

I would like to give to securely access to USER1 to folder /var/www/html/WEBSITE
I followed this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/598870/limit-sftp-user-access-to-specified-directory), so connection will be with sftp.

When i connect with root acount on sftp with filezilla, the symbolic link is redirected me the /var/www/html/WEBSITE but when i'm connected with USER1 account i couldn't access to the target folder.

Thanks and sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that the `User1`/`USER1` (or however you named it) has the access to the real directory `/var/www/html/WEBSITE`, not only to the symlink.

This is usually made by defining a new group for that user and `apache`/`www-data` and allowing the the access for this group. The rights should depend on what the user should be able to do there. But for the start, reading something about [Unix Permission](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-file-permission.htm) is good start

Comment: I changed file/folder owner to USERS1:sftp but still have problem accessing folder/files with user USER1, it should take time to be effective?
Thanks.

Comment: no. It is immediate. How?

Comment: I retested and it's working when i changed my website folder owner to USER1 my problem now is that the user have acess to all directories how to restrict its access to only its home folder?
Thanks.